# Does "candlelight" mean "compare side by side"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Some of my colleagues use the word "candlelight" to mean "directly compare similar things".

A specific example is comparing two lines on a line chart like this:

[image: Example of line chart with several series]

> "We can use this chart to candlelight result groups"

I cannot find any references to this meaning of the word. Is it a recognised use of the word and, if so, what is its etymology?

Comment: I have added a example relating to the chart.

Comment: It is not related to stock markets, and they are native English speakers.

Comment: Candlelight as a verb can refer to examining eggs by holding in front of a candlelight (traditionally). Perhaps by analogy this is being used to say particular things are being taken up for examination.

Comment: They probably mean 'highlight' .

Comment: Joews - gotchya.  Josh -- that's a good guess.  Maybe it's that simple.  Joews -- are YOU a native English speaker?  Is there a chance you misunderstood them, an they said "highlight"?

Comment: Regarding what Neil said -- is your company involved in the production of chickens or eggs??

Comment: I am also a native English speaker, and there are no chickens, eggs or related entities involved (it's a software company). I am quite certain that it is "candelight", not any similar sounding word. The chicken extrapolation hypothesis (!) sounds good.

Comment: None of the context makes sense to define candlelight. The graph is generic (of course it is) but it's not enough of a clue to provide context for something that is generally considered a dim light source, relatively speaking. Likewise the example sentence given is useless to provide anything to define. Am I going to burn the chart with a candle? Is it going to be minimally visible? What do your colleagues say it means?

Comment: Anything about candlelight comparison in web search is related to actual comparison of cameras taking dark pictures of candle-lit scenes.

Comment: It's a new one on me, but could it mean 'something less rigorous than "highlight"'?

Comment: @Josh61: It must be at least *feasible* that the speaker was facetiously punning on ***highlight*** - on the grounds that the results for Groups 14/15 don't unambiguously distinguish those two (and noting the numbering system, perhaps results for Groups 3-12 were so mixed up they were excluded from the chart because they didn't show/highlight *anything* meaningful). Whatever - it looks like a one-off usage to me. With no further context it's either POB or rare domain-specific jargon, so I think it's Off Topic.

Comment: @joews, have you thought of simply asking your colleagues what it means? Or would that be opening yourself up to ridicule, not being part of the team, ego-crushing.......

Comment: I have asked what they mean - they are certain of the meaning. Several other colleagues, including myself, didn't know the term, so I decided to look into its origins. Hence the question. There aren't any idiots involved, let's keep it civil.

Comment: Since you decided to post your question here, at the English Academy, for resolution, you can take some satisfaction at knowing that, to many experts here, this use of *candlelight* is meaningless, and why it was used is a mystery. As for why your colleagues feel confident that this use is fitting and meaningful is for them to explain, which apparently they haven't. You might discover the reason by posing a question at [the other Academy](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com). If you return with their reply, we can translate it into more familiar words, like *lazy*, *arrogant*, or *insecure*.

Comment: A candlestick is a way to visualize errors in a graph. As displayed here http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/candlesticks.html.

Comment: For eggs I've always heard it called "candling".  The speaker may have had in mind "holding them up to the light", which you might do with two such charts, such that light shines through and allows you to compare them.

Comment: The verb for evaluating eggs using light is "candle", not "candelight".

Comment: @Neil: do you have any evidence for egg-examining using specifically the term *candle_light_*? Like Hot Licks, Jace, and others, I've only ever heard it called *candle/candling*.

Comment: I think Group 14 should have paid attention to the other groups. I don't know if Group 15 really needed the other groups to invade its personal space.

Comment: Having raised chickens and *candled* eggs myself, I can say with confidence that -- at least on the west coast of the US -- the term "candlelighting" is not used for that activity.

Comment: As well as eggs, it's common to use a candle when decanting port or older wine (old enough to have sediment) to make sure sediment ends in the neck of the bottle and not in the decanter. In these days of battery-powered torches it remains common because people still often have candles on their dinner table. It seems reasonable that "candlelight" to mean examining eggs or wine came to be used first more generally (to examine anything) and then more specific (to compare two things) within a particular group, but that's no more than conjecture about what is possible.

Comment: This is a long shot, but maybe you're hearing "We can use this chart to *count alike* result groups"?

Comment: @CaseyChu Great suggestion.  It's possible someone at his business a long time ago heard a phrase like that wrong, and it's since become jargon specific to that particular work place.  Of course, there's no way to know for sure.

Comment: I would have said the correct words in their sentence would have been 'correlate', or 'analyse', but they're not quite close enough a homophone. 'co-analyze' is, though, and has the right meaning. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coanalyze

Comment: @Marthaª there is some usage of it to be found through google, but I think _candling_ is standard term as Doktor J suggests.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead an put in an **official answer** to the **actual question**.

"Is it a recognised use of the word?"

The simple answer is, very strongly,

## "No."

your friends / fellow inmates / bosses are either

(i) using a very strange "inside" terminology - perhaps from some specific technical field

(ii) using an "inside joke" -- some linguistic quirk that has built up between them.

(iii) they are using a confused - essentially "wrong", "silly" - mishearing or similar mistake.

A vast number of highly intelligent / professionally linguistic / literate people are on this 'ere list; and nobody's cottoned-on to anything.

So honestly, the answer to your specific question is "No"

I can confidently speak for the entire mailing list, when I say, we'd love some feedback on just what they meant.  Cheers!

Comment: Which mailing list are you talking about?

Answer (score 17):

Note that [**candlestick charting**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart) is a technical term used in talking about stock markets.

Is there a chance this is the term you overheard?

(To be clear, the actual image you present looks *nothing* like a candlestick chart in any way. But there may have been some confusion.)

---

*Candle* as a verb can refer to examining eggs by holding in front of a candle.

It's very vague, but this makes me think of when you **hold something up to a lightsource** like this ...

[image: A man in a white coat holding an X-ray picture of a hand in front of a wall-mounted illuminated viewer]

Conceivably, your colleagues have in mind something related to: holding one up to the other with a light source behind.

But it's totally confused, and not in any way an idiom or anything that makes sense.  Almost certainly, it is **simply a mishearing** somewhere along the chain.

Comment: A note, the primary image on Wikipedia is simplified.  Check out [candlestick highlighting graphs](https://www.google.com/search?q=candlestick+highlight+graph&tbm=isch) - it uses coloration to show change.  And "**candle**stick high**light**" almost fits...  Except not the image in the question.

Comment: Hi @Izkata !  Don't quite follow you?  "candlestick charts" are a well-established format for market trading charts.  (For instance, simply click to any online stock chart service whatsoever - say google or yahoo - and you can click the "candlestick" option to see a candlestick chart.).  C/S charts have a black body if positive, white if negative (they didn't have red/green in 1700 :) )

Comment: (err ... white/black, of course :) )

Comment: On Wikipedia, while it has a description further down for increasing/decreasing, the primary image at the top is one solid color.  Both types are used, and I often see the colored one specified as a "highlighted" version.

Comment: Note that despite what Neil said, the accepted verb for examining eggs in front of a candle is *to candle* or *candling*, never *candlelighting*.

Comment: Hey Martha -- that's an outstanding point.

Comment: I gave -1 for the reference to candlestick charts as it is clearly not what the OP is talking about. I'd revert / reverse that for the egg testing idea if the candlestick charts portion was removed.

Comment: @TecBrat: the answer clearly says that the OP's chart is nothing like a candlestick chart. That doesn't preclude the possibility that the origin of this misused term is somebody mishearing or misunderstanding "candlestick chart".

Comment: what the hell is that amazing like "power of 'a'" thing on nickname?  so cool

Answer (score 6):

I have not come across this usage.  My guess is that it is derived from the practise of candling eggs to check for development of the embryo. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candling

Comment: I agree that this is probably the origin, but there's still a misconception at hand, because *candling* is only ever *candling*, never *candlelighting*.

Comment: also, candling doesn't compare eggs, it merely shows qualities in an individual egg.

Answer (score 3):

A sensible use of the concept "to candlelight" would be to display something in subdued or favourable light in order to conceal blemishes (faults). Whereas "in the harsh light of day" those faults would be more obvious.  Hence "candle-lit dinners". Normal usage would be in the context of criticising someone else for "candle-lighting".  One would not expect somebody who was engaged in "candle-lighting" to admit as much to the victim(s). But they might use the term when plotting with conspirators to deceive someone else.

Comment: This doesn't fit the OP's description of how it is used, but I like it. "That spike at the end of the graph is not going to go over well with the CFO. We've gotta **candlelight** it — tweak the scale, move the data points a bit, and make it look like we didn't expense that trip to Vegas."

Comment: I like this too. I think the OP should tell his colleagues "Oh yeah, I know that term, but you're using it wrong!" and explain it just as steveOw and @iamnotmaynard did here.

Comment: Purely speculation but how about "we will show the customer this graph which demonstrates that complaints are dropping in all departments. OK I know group 14 looks bad but we will **candlelight** it by giving it a pale green color on a white background"?

Comment: @BrianLacy: Exactly!

Answer (score 2):

It appears from a [web search](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=candlelight+comparison) that it is popular to see how cameras perform in low-light situations, especially those lit by a candle.

It would be reasonable to assume someone took the noun *candlelight* from this and applied it as a generic term for comparison. Admittedly, it's a bit of a stretch to assume that the light source is now verbified to use as a term for comparison, but there is nothing obvious about the sentence or the graph that a casual observer would immediately associate candlelight with comparison in either context.

Comment: i see that as a real stretch, brother. it seems very unlikely!!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is:

- If results are on separate charts (separate bits of paper) then they're difficult to compare.
- If you put the papers together and put a candle behind them (without setting fire to the paper) then with light shining through the papers you can see all results together and compare them.

That's my guess, based on the meaning you stated in the OP.

It's non-standard: I would not have guessed "compare the results" if you hadn't told me that's what they meant.

Comment: Chris, I think you are likely correct. There is an image that you might consider adding to your answer on the Wikipedia page for silhouettes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette by way of confirmation that someone somewhere once used a candle to see the shape of something...

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the expression to mean not so much "to compare side by side" but rather just "to scrutinize" as if by holding it up to a light source to see the finer details. It seems to me that you can "candlelight" those lines on the graph, and comparing them is one way to do so.

Comment: Except if you've ever had to work by candlelight, you'll know that it's spectacularly ineffective at highlighting fine details. Unless of course you light a couple of dozen candles, so the flickering of one is offset by a whole bunch of others... but the fact remains that a lightbulb would be much more effective.

Comment: what did people do before lightbulbs? never were able to scrutinize anything until 1879?

Comment: Octopus, they lit a couple dozen candles, or they worked during daylight hours. Actually, mostly, they worked during daylight hours.

Comment: Lol Martha - again totally correct.  I can't think of a worse analogy to use than "candlelight".  Indeed **the normal term is spotlight**, of course.